# Value of iterator variable doesn't change?

Tags: c#, marshalling, unmanaged

SOLVED -> SEE ANSWER BELOW

Okay, this will be my first question here, so if I made some mistake with the question itself, please point out and I'll try to fix it.

I'm trying to learn how to get managed and unmanaged code to interoperate, so as a learning project I'm trying to dump the IAT table of notepad.exe from the memory, using C#.

So, given the following piece of code:

```
protected void DumpEntries_IAT()
{
    List<string> importedFunctions = new List<string>();
    int sizeOfEntry = Marshal.SizeOf(new PEHeaders.ImageImportDescriptor());
    long numberOfEntries = peHeaders.OptionalHeader64.IAT.Size/sizeOfEntry - 1; // Last entry is empty.
    Console.WriteLine("Number of IAT entries: {0}", numberOfEntries);
    Console.ReadKey(true);
    int bytesRead = 0;
    Console.WriteLine(peHeaders.OptionalHeader64.IAT.VirtualAddress.ToString("X"));
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfEntries; i++)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[sizeOfEntry];
        ReadProcessMemory64(processHandle.ToInt64(), process.MainModule.BaseAddress.ToInt64() + peHeaders.OptionalHeader64.IAT.VirtualAddress + i*sizeOfEntry, buffer, buffer.Length, ref bytesRead);
        PEHeaders.ImageImportDescriptor entry = new PEHeaders.ImageImportDescriptor();
        entry = UnmanagedInterop.FromBytes<PEHeaders.ImageImportDescriptor>(buffer);
        ReadProcessMemory64(processHandle.ToInt64(), process.MainModule.BaseAddress.ToInt64() + i*sizeOfEntry + entry.OriginalFirstThunk, buffer, buffer.Length, ref bytesRead);
        PEHeaders.ImageThunkData thunkData = new PEHeaders.ImageThunkData();
        buffer = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(thunkData)];
        ReadProcessMemory64(processHandle.ToInt64(), process.MainModule.BaseAddress.ToInt64() + entry.OriginalFirstThunk, buffer, buffer.Length, ref bytesRead);
        thunkData = UnmanagedInterop.FromBytes<PEHeaders.ImageThunkData>(buffer);
        Console.WriteLine("Address of ImageImportByName is {0}", thunkData.AddressOfData.ToString("X"));
        Console.WriteLine("i= {0}", i);
        Console.ReadKey(true); // Since the value of i stays zero, it's effectively an infinite loop, so I had to add that to actually read the output.
    }
}
```

I get the following results:

```
Dumping IAT...
Number of IAT entries: 90
1D000
Address of ImageImportByName is 0
i= 0
Address of ImageImportByName is 100001
i= 0
Address of ImageImportByName is 100001
i= 0
Address of ImageImportByName is 100001
i= 0
Address of ImageImportByName is 100001
i= 0
Address of ImageImportByName is 100001
i= 0
```

As it can be seen from the output, the variable `i` always seem to be having a value of zero, even though it should be increased at the end of every iteration. Since the code is running multiple times, the loop is itself seems to sort of work.

I have tried searching around, but I didn't really find anything related, and I can't figure out what is happening. Even though I'm trying to operate with unmanaged code and memory (ReadProcessMemory and Marshal.PtrToStructure are both involved), `i` is a local managed variable that should only exist in the scope of the `for` loop, and it's value isn't changed in the code anywhere else but by the `i++' instruction in the loop.

Any ideas what might be the cause of this behaviour?

Note: I have tried creating an iterator variable outside the `for` declaration and changing it with instructions `i++` and `i += 1` at the end of the loop, it still stays zero.

Comment: for(int i = 0; i < numberOfEntries; i++) -> Until now, I believied that should increase i at the end of every iteration.

Comment: Try to create a complete example that we can just paste into Visual Studio and test for ourselves.

Comment: C# `for` loops syntax matches other C-style languages such as C++. There is nothing wrong with your `for` loop. Something else is causing a problem with your variable.

Comment: I guess I'll just upload the whole thing to github, as it consists of multiple classes with a bit of inheritance. I'm using SharpDevelop, so I guess Visual Studio can open my project?

Comment: Please at least try to make the code as small as possible. If you eliminate all the code that isn't required to reproduce it, you're a good way toward solving it.

Comment: Okay: so, if I comment out the lines with ReadProcessMemory, i seems to iterate fine again... which is weird because I don't set it's value in those lines, I merely use it for a multiplication (i*sizeOfEntry).

Comment: I have now written the value of i to the console before and after each call to ReadProcessMemory, and in the second iteration *before* the RPM call, it is 1 as it should be. After any call to RPM i is zero.

Comment: Okay, if I just move the declaration for i out of the loop, it still becomes zero, *but* if declare another variable just before the loop... then `i` suddenly starts working as intended. The new variable however, *still* produces the problem. I believe ReadProcessMemory isn't supposed to overwrite any of these variables, and I'm pretty sure it isn't PtrToStructure, because if I comment those lines instead and leave calls to rpm in place, I can still reproduce the strange behavior.

Comment: i'd assume a bug in RPM. try to pad the buffer with a few extra bytes.

Comment: @speising: Thanks for the tip, I already did that and was just writing the answer when you commented. It was my fault, and not RPM's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, turns out I was just stupid.

I used a 32-bit C example to set up DLLImport for ReadProcessMemory like that:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint="ReadProcessMemory")]
protected static extern bool ReadProcessMemory64(Int64 hProcess, Int64 lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, int dwSize, ref int lpNumberOfBytesRead);
```

As you can see, I have changed the uint (32-bit) decalaration of *some* of the input parameters like  lpBaseAddress (because my system is 64-bit) to Int64 to make it fit... but forgot about others!

Now, I declared the variables in this order:

```
int bytesRead = 0; // 32 bits of data...
for(int i = 0; // <-- Another 32 bit integer, *just right next* to bytesRead in the memory...
```

Then called ReadProcessMemory like that:

```
ReadProcessMemory64(processHandle, memoryAddress, buffer, buffer.Length, ref bytesRead);
```

The last parameter is the key. Turns out on 64-bit RPM expects a pointer to a 64-bit integer, and I passed it a pointer to a 32-bit one. Being unmanaged, it wrote a 64-bit integer to that address without any error. That means half the 64-bit integer overwrites the next 32-bits of whatever is next to readBytes in the memory, which happened to be the `i` variable.

ReadProcessMemory should be more like this:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint="ReadProcessMemory")]
protected static extern bool ReadProcessMemory64(Int64 hProcess, Int64 lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, Int64 dwSize, ref Int64 lpNumberOfBytesRead);
```

And readBytes of course, should be `Int64`. Problem solved.